# performance overhead of typecasting variables in C

Tags: c, performance, x86

I have seen people recommending to avoid typecasting of variables as much as possible in high performing applications. I never understood the reason for this and I tend to typecast lot of times mostly to avoid compiler warning. Does this have any implications on performance?.
Commonly seen code:

1) `struct X *` pass to a function which takes `void *`

2)`uint16_t` typecasted to `uint32_t`

Comment: Type-casting is mostly done during compilation-time (not sure about fixed-point to floating-point and vice-versa, but most definitely for pointer types), so there are no runtime implications whatsoever.

Comment: Common sense suggests that conversion to/from floating point should take some CPU cycles...

Comment: @iharob: You deleted your answer, so I will refer to your last comment here. Floating-point types are typically represented in IEEE-754 format (not sure whether or not the C-language standard dictates that). For example, 4.0 and 4 are potentially represented with "completely different bits". So casting between them mandates some sort of operation that would be executed during runtime.

Comment: Think in terms of assembly also, for example in x86, uint16_t assigned to to uint32_t. Now I vaguely remember, the move instruction need to zero the upper 2 bytes. What about that overhead?.

Comment: Moreover, with signed integral types it might involve sign extension..

Comment: @deadbeef: OP asks about pointer-type casting. Those cannot possibly be different in size.

Comment: @barakmanos Pointers to different types *are not restricted* to be equal size.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: By language standard or in practice (and if in practice, then could you say what platform)?

Comment: @barakmanos By the standard - definitely. And I am pretty sure I've heard about a specific platform. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @barakmanos Take a look [here](http://www.techanswering.com/question/show/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: This, in conjunction with the notion that casting to a bigger type requires an additional runtime operation (padding with zeros), could serve as a very good answer IMO.

Comment: @barakmanos If you can consolidate it into an answer - the community will be thankful :) I am too lazy..

Comment: *I tend to typecast lot of times mostly to avoid compiler warning.*  You're doing it wrong.  That's just papering over real problems.  Think about it like this:  the people who wrote the compiler you're using to turn your source code into a runnable binary *took extra time to tell you they think what you're doing is dodgy*.  Don't ignore that - they know a lot more about turning code into a running binary than you do.

Comment: This is not a matter of performance, but letting the compiler help you find errors. Thus: **only** typecast iff 1) There is no other way - considering all aspects, **and** 2) You fully understand _all_ implications **and** 3) You completely accept them.

Answer (score 20):

> Does [casting] have any implications on performance?

Not directly.  A type cast expresses an explicit *conversion* of a value from one data type to another.  It is really the conversion that has the potential for a performance impact, and if such a conversion is going to be performed whether you cast or not, then the cast has no performance impact whatever.

For example, some compilers can be set to warn about implicit conversions from floating-point types to integer types, and often these warnings can be silenced by making the conversion explicit with a cast.  That does not change the fact that a conversion will be performed, and that such conversions are not free, but the cast doesn't make the conversion any more expensive than it otherwise would be.

Additionally, some conversions can be implemented for free.  For example, on most machines, signed and unsigned integer types with of the same width have compatible representations, so converting values between these types is a no-op.  Casts that only add or remove type qualifiers other than `_Atomic` are also in this category.

With regard to your specific examples:

> 1) `struct X *` pass to a function which takes `void *`

C does not require compatible representations for different pointer types, but in practice it is rare these days for different object pointer types to have different representations.  Therefore, conversions between pointer types are usually free.  That hardly matters, however, because the specific case you ask about is one in which the conversion will be performed whether you insert an explicit cast or not.

> 2) `uint16_t` typecasted to `uint32_t`

This may be free, depending on specific circumstances and compiler implementation.  For example, if the value being converted was already being held in a 32-bit register, then it is a no-op.  Additionally, the compiler might be able to implement it as a no-op in the specific expression in which it appears.  Note also that if `uint32_t` is the same as `unsigned int`, as is common, then C semantics require this particular conversion to be performed *routinely* in the evaluation of arithmetic expressions, so many of these fall into the category of conversions that will happen whether you cast or not.